# How to check if a download with Aws::Transfer::Transfermanager was a success?

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I do a download from AWS S3 and at the end of the method I want to return the success of it but sadly I don't know how to.

I tried to do this with the TransferHandle I get but there does not seem to be an option for this.

```
bool downloadObject(const std::shared_ptr<Aws::S3::S3Client> & client, const Aws::String &key_name)
{
const auto executor = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Utils::Threading::PooledThreadExecutor>("Downloading-File", 4);
auto transferInitCallback = [&](const Aws::Transfer::TransferManager*, const std::shared_ptr<const Aws::Transfer::TransferHandle>& handle) {};

Aws::Transfer::TransferManagerConfiguration transferConfig(executor.get());
transferConfig.s3Client = client;
transferConfig.transferInitiatedCallback = transferInitCallback;

const auto transmanager = Aws::Transfer::TransferManager::Create(transferConfig);
const auto handle = transmanager->DownloadFile("bucketName", key_name, "C:/Development/test.gz");

handle->WaitUntilFinished();    // block calling thread until download complete

//if download == success -> return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetStatus`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_transfer_1_1_transfer_handle.html#a2ee403dc366f6bbd2675dfacc8b0cf22) to check for success, e.g.:

```
return handle->GetStatus() == Aws::Transfer::TransferStatus::COMPLETED
```